# Add option to Magento system admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I would like to add a textbox to the Header block located inside System>Config>Design>Header, the location in the image below.

[image: location of input box]

I know this has to be done in xml, but I am not sure where. Also how would I display that in an phtml file?

Comment: Are you familiar with creating Magento modules ?

Comment: Not really. I did find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869335/magento-change-product-page-titles-to-include-attributes) on creating a module, but as far as tapping into magento's classes and functions, i am very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml` you will find the configuration that Magento reads to show those fields, for example the "Small Logo Image src" is a field called `logo_src_small`. The needed is a module that will tell Magento about:

1. The extra field in the admin panel under header.

   ```
   <config>
       <sections>
           <design>
               <groups>
               <header>
               <fields>
               <new_field translate="label">
                 <label>New Field</label>
                 <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                 <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                 <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                 <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                 <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
               </new_field>
               </fields>
               </header>
               </groups>
           </design>
       </section>
   </config>
   ```
2. Rewrite the block class  `code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php` so you can add the method that will expose the new field.
3. In the app/design/frontend/{Package}/{Theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml you can easily call `$this->getNewField()` where getNewField() is the method you have in the class we overridden in point 2.

A couple of links to help you start:

- http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/22/magento-part8-series-systemxml/
- http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/10/27/custom-configuration-fields-in-magento.html
- http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78175/add-custom-field-in-admin-system-configuration-sales

Answer (score 0):

First add a field  in system.xml file which is located in

app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml,under header section

```
<header translate="label">
    ..........
        <welcome_massage translate="label">
            <label>Welcome Massage</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>35</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </welcome_massage>
    </fields>
</header>
```

Then add a method in header block , app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php

```
public function getWelcomeMassage()
{
    return $this->_data['welcome_massage'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome_massage') ;
}
```

Last call this method in header.phtml file,  like that

```
<?php echo $this->getWelcomeMassage() ?>
```

> Note : You see that I have code in core files. You should rewrite the
>   core files.

[Overriding Magento blocks, models, helpers and controllers](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

[Overwrite system.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266817/magento-1-7-overwrite-system-xml)

Comment: Since the welcome text box already existed I just used echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome')

Comment: I just uses arbitrary text box, you can change it as per your desire.